# Log android auto while connected to car

Tags: android, logcat, android-auto

How can I get the logs for android auto when connected to my car?  I have `Force logging` but not sure how to actually record logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can always take a [bugreport](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report.html) from the device later on after some testing. To see the logs in real time as its connected to the car, you can checkout the ADB documentation on how to [Connect to a device over Wi-Fi](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless), and use a laptop to connect with since the usb connection will be used on the phone to connect to the car or DHU.

Once the phone is connected with the laptop, you can open a terminal and stream the logcat there.